# Committed JDO writes do not apply on local GAE HRD, or possibly reused transaction

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, jdo

I'm using JDO 2.3 on app engine.  I was using the Master/Slave datastore for local testing and recently switched over to using the HRD datastore for local testing, and parts of my app are breaking (which is to be expected).  One part of the app that's breaking is where it sends a lot of writes quickly - that is because of the 1-second limit thing, it's failing with a concurrent modification exception.

Okay, so that's also to be expected, so I have the browser retry the writes again later when they fail (maybe not the best hack but I'm just trying to get it working quickly).

But a weird thing is happening.  Some of the writes which should be succeeding (the ones that DON'T get the concurrent modification exception) are also failing, even though the commit phase completes and the request returns my success code.  I can see from the log that the retried requests are working okay, but these other requests that seem to have committed on the first try are, I guess, never "applied."  But from what I read about the Apply phase, writing again to that same entity should force the apply... but it doesn't.

Code follows.  Some things to note:

1. I am attempting to use [automatic JDO caching](http://ukena.de/content/enabling-jdo-caching-google-app-engine).  So this is where JDO uses memcache under the covers.  This doesn't actually work unless you wrap everything in a transaction.
2. all the requests are doing is reading a string out of an entity, modifying part of the string, and saving that string back to the entity.  If these requests weren't in transactions, you'd of course have the "dirty read" problem.  But with transactions, isolation is supposed to be at the level of "serializable" so I don't see what's happening here.
3. the entity being modified is a root entity (not in a group)
4. I have cross-group transactions enabled

The relevant code (this is a simplified version):

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getManager();
Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
String responsetext = "";
try {
    tx.begin();
    // I have extra calls to "makePersistent" because I found that relying
    // on pm.close didn't always write the objects to cache, maybe that
    // was only a DataNucleus 1.x issue though
    Key userkey = obtainUserKeyFromCookie();
    User u = pm.getObjectById(User.class, userkey);
    pm.makePersistent(u); // to make sure it gets cached for next time
    Key mapkey = obtainMapKeyFromQueryString();
    // this is NOT a java.util.Map, just FYI
    Map currentmap = pm.getObjectById(Map.class, mapkey);
    Text mapData = currentmap.getMapData(); // mapData is JSON stored in the entity
    Text newMapData = parseModifyAndReturn(mapData); // transform the map
    currentmap.setMapData(newMapData); // mutate the Map object
    pm.makePersistent(currentmap); // make sure to persist so there is a cache hit
    tx.commit();
    responsetext = "OK";
} catch (JDOCanRetryException jdoe) {
    // log jdoe
    responsetext = "RETRY";
} catch (Exception e) {
    // log e
    responsetext = "ERROR";
} finally {
    if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
    pm.close();
}
resp.getWriter().println(responsetext);
```

**UPDATE**: I am pretty sure I know why this is happening, but I will still award the bounty to anyone who can confirm it.

Basically, I think the problem is that transactions are not really implemented in the local version of the datastore.  References:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/gVMS1dFSpcU
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/deGasFdIO-M
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!msg/google-appengine-java/4YuNb6TVD6I/gSttMmHYwo0J

Because transactions are not implemented, rollback is essentially a no-op.  Therefore, I get a dirty read when two transactions try to modify the record at the same time.  In other words, A reads the data and B reads the data at the same time.  A attempts to modify the data, and B attempts to modify a different part of the data.  A writes to the datastore, then B writes, obliterating A's changes.  Then B is "rolled back" by app engine, but since rollbacks are a no-op when running on the local datastore, B's changes stay, and A's do not.  Meanwhile, since B is the thread that threw the exception, the client retries B, but does not retry A (since A was supposedly the transaction that succeeded).

Comment: Have you thought of redesigning your datastore and how you use it, in order to avoid persisting to the same entity group more than once per second? Alternatively, have you tried handing off persisting to the datastore to enqueued tasks, and arranging things to respect the 1/s entity group write frequency limit?

Comment: I have thought of that.  But before I do that, I'd like to understand why this particular bug is happening... my concern is that I fundamentally don't understand something about the HRD or app engine/jdo transactions or something, or that I missed something in the documentation, and it's going to bite me later, because I have at least 25 other services that I need to add transactions to (JDO caching won't work if datastore accesses are not in a transaction)

Comment: FWIW, using current plugin (GAE JDO v2.x), I see no requirement for access to be in a transaction for the L2 cache to work; if an object is read in then it is L2 cached and if it isn't then it ought to be reported (obviously the old plugin isn't supported so only report such a thing if with the current).

Comment: @DataNucleus upgraded to new plugin, got same behavior.  What I don't understand is that the code does two datastore reads, then a write.  When caching is enabled, you would think the two reads would come from cache, so the only thing that would go to the ds would be the write.  But that's not what happens.  Instead, the only billed transaction is one datastore read, and no datastore writes occur.  Why?

Comment: @DataNucleus: and just to clarify, when the two reads and the single write are not in a transaction, then there's no caching: all three of these operations go to the datastore.

Comment: you present no code for "do datastore stuff", and all depends if objects are actually in the cache in the first place. getObjectById will obviously try L1 then L2 caches first then go to datastore (as per the log) ... irrespective of txn or not.

Comment: Hi @DataNucleus... I added the code for "do datastore stuff", sorry about that.  I hugely appreciate any insight you might have in this issue.  The page modifies the same map over and over again so after the first req, if it's being cached then is should come from cache.  With version 2.0 of DataNucleus I don't have to specify the extra cache stuff in jdoconfig, it caches automatically (but you knew that).  Basically, without the transaction, it doesn't come from cache for some reason, and when it is caching, it does a single read instead of a write (per appstats), which makes no sense to me

Comment: With DN v3 (GAE plugin v2) you get L2 caching *in an internal map* by default NOT in memcached, and you still have to specify extra caching stuff (datanucleus.cache.level2.type=jcache) to use memcached. All of our tests demonstrate that you need no "makePersistent" when you're not making something persistent, and that any nontx usage will load from cache, and if pulling in from datastore will then L2 cache the object (look at the log)

Comment: @DataNucleus -- I have verified this multiple times using appstats.  When the above code is NOT wrapped in a transaction,
JDO performs two datastore reads and one write, 3 RPC's, at a cost of 240.  Not just the first time,
every time, even though it is accessing the same record every time hence should be pulling it from
cache.  However, when I wrap the code in a transaction as above, the code makes 4 RPC's: begin transaction,
get, put, and commit -- of these, only the Get is billed as a datastore read, so the overall cost is 70.

Comment: @DataNucleus -- No idea why app engine decides to bill me for the read instead of the write.  Maybe appstats is the wrong tool
to determine whether the data is actually being pulled from cache? --
my main reason for implementing cache is to reduce datastore
reads and reduce my bill -- could app engine be billing me the same amount for non-transactional cache reads as it does for
datastore reads?  why?

Comment: JDO performs what it says in the DN log, nothing more. All datastore interaction is logged (PUT, GET etc). "appstats" is something at Google's end and you better take it up with them what it is doing since it has no connection with this plugin. The way of verifying what DN does is looking at the log (and in the public code).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe bad news for you, I left JDO and I'm using Objectify and at some places directly datanucleus. I have a perfect control over my persistence which is a performance and design better choice (if you think in the long term).

Because the db is no-sql, there are structural changes against JPA, JDO and standard assumptions:

Using the native datanucleus API you can do things that are not in standard JPA nor even in Objectify : The example I used was to create columns dynamically

The transaction is not present in GAE, there is something that can sometimes look like a transaction (entity groups). So using the native API will avoid you doing such imprevisible gymnastics.

Trying to drive a car with a joystick could work, but there are surely new things to learn. In my opinion it is worth learning the native way

Comment: Zied is right.  While it is mildly interesting that Google provides the JPA and JDO abstraction layers, I have never seen a project that went terribly well with them.  It usually ends in all sorts of nasty hacks due to the fact that people keep thinking of the backing datastore as an RDBMS when it is most certainly not.  I would strongly suggest people not use the JPA or JDO libraries and use either the raw Google API or Objectify.